# Android Screen Activation

Tags: android

hey friends ! I want to run a background process  when my android screen is active for 
first time . How can i accomplish this.
Please help me ?

Comment: What do you mean by "android screen is active for the first time" ? Do you want to say when the device is booted ?

Answer (score 1):

The idea is pretty simple, but there are some questions that you have to tackle later.

Just bind a service in your activity's oncreate method. I suggest that you use the IntentService to extend your custom service. Create a runnable in your service and perform whatever operation you need to perform. The catch here is, the lifecycle of the Service is  managed by your Activity and when the Activity is destroyed, the service will also die.
So if you want the operation to continue beyond the lifecycle of your activity, you need to manage the life cycle of the service seperately. Using startService method. (startService --> onStartCommand--> Stop)